# Webbrowser .NET Control with Birt Viewer Report printing session expired issue

Tags: .net, forms, printing, webbrowser-control, birt

I have created a Windows Forms application with Webbrowser control. Inside this webbrowser control, I have opened a birt report and its working fine.

But when I click on print icon, a new IE popup window opened with exception "Viewing Session expired or not valid".

However, this report working fine in every browser including internet explorer and printing also works. I have tried to disable the safe mode of IE and security set to very low. But nothing happend.

Webbrowser control gives the same exception. I have used hack to simulate the webbrowser control to my latest version (IE 11) and it load in IE as IE 11.

Can anyone tell that either how to disable the Viewing session security in Birt?
(in web.xml, I have tried to change the paraments but nothing happens)

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of debugging then I get to know that Birt Viewer checks for new session based on document location. 
The .NET IE control location is project directory while when open a popup window then it's location is Intert explorer in c: drive.

Therefore always getting session expire problem. Just simply remove this security from Servlet class and then there is no such problem.... :)